# How to remove weekends from Simple Gantt Chart Excel model?

Tags: microsoft-excel, gantt

I'm using the Simple Gantt Chart from the office package, and I like it, but it display Sat and Sun as well, which is irrelevant.. could you help me edit it please?

The current formula appears to be:

`=Project_Start-WEEKDAY(Project_Start,1)+2+7*(Display_Week-1)`

as in the attached picture.

Thank you!

[image: Screenshot of Excel-sheet]

Comment: Look at using `WORKDAY` instead of `WEEKDAY`, or `WORKDAY.INTL` for even more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you could manually hide the Saturday and Sunday columns.  (Select the Column header, right-click, Hide.)  When the chart is scrolled with the value in E4 it retains the hidden columns.